# No data shown in Accordion of a repeater

Tags: asp.net, accordion, repeater

In setting up a repeater, I have an accordion inside of it.  When I run it, it does connect the data, the right number of times indicating that it binds correctly, but it is not displaying any information inside of the accordioan

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptMain">
                <HeaderTemplate>  Stuff
                </HeaderTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"strTitle")  %>
                    <ajax:Accordion ID="acdClass" runat="server" FadeTransitions="true" AutoSize="None" RequireOpenedPane="false" SelectedIndex="-1">
                        <Panes>
                            <ajax:AccordionPane ID="panTitle1" runat="server">
                                <Header>
                               Accrdion Header -    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"strTitle")  %>
                                </Header>
                                <Content>
                                    Content Info -<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"strTitle")  %>
                                </Content>
                            </ajax:AccordionPane>
                        </Panes>
                    </ajax:Accordion>
                </ItemTemplate>
</Repeater>
```

The issue occurs where  it will display the correct information on the binding outside of the accordion, but seems to ignore it on the inside.  I know it is binding correctly, but it is acting ignorant when it is in inside of the accordion.    I've seen a few cases of how to do it with the accordion on the outside, but looking to do it on the inside.

Any ideas?

Wade

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try putting repeater inside accordion instead.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptMain" OnItemDataBound="rptMain_ItemDataBound">
                <HeaderTemplate>  Stuff
                </HeaderTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"strTitle")  %>
                    <ajax:Accordion ID="acdClass" runat="server" FadeTransitions="true" AutoSize="None" RequireOpenedPane="false" SelectedIndex="-1">
                        <Panes>
                            <ajax:AccordionPane ID="panTitle1" runat="server">
                                <Header>
                               Accrdion Header -    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"strTitle")  %>
                                </Header>
                                <Content>
                                    Content Info -<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"strTitle")  %>
                                </Content>
                            </ajax:AccordionPane>
                        </Panes>
                    </ajax:Accordion>
                </ItemTemplate>
</Repeater>

protected void rptMain_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
{
    //Find your accordion and set data accordionly using e.Item.FindControl("acdClass") as Accordion;
}
    }
```

Comment: I am still not sure why you would put an repeater inside the accordion.  I am hoping to have up to 200+ accordion and everything seems to be working except displaying the databind.

Answer (score 0):

i avoided it and using Bootstrap CSS

```
data-target="#collapse<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"intCount")  %>
```

and then

```
<div id="collapse<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"intCount")  %>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

Not what I wanted but it did work.